# アクセス先のWebアプリから、monacaアプリであることを検知したい

Tags: monaca

アプリ内部にHTMLを含むのではなく、外部サーバに設置したページをロードする仕組みでmonacaアプリを制作したいと思っています。

そこで、外部サーバのページから、そのページにアクセスしたのがIEやChromeなどの通常のブラウザか、monacaアプリかを検知・区別することは可能でしょうか。

細かくは下記の条件で検討しています。

1. 可能であればアプリ以外のアクセスを拒否したい。そのため、偽装しにくい情報であればベター。
2. 会員登録機能のないサイトのため、ユーザ認証以外の手段である必要がある。

もし情報をお持ちの方は、書き込みしていただければ嬉しいです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

「ユーザ認証以外の手段である必要がある」との事ですが、やろうとしている事は認証だと思います。
ユーザ毎にアクセス用のID・認証キーを作るのでは無く、アプリケーション共通のID・認証キーを用いればよいです。

ただ、そのID・認証キーはアプリケーションに埋め込むことになるので、アプリケーションの中身を覗かれれば、偽装に必要な情報を取られてしまいます。
ここらへんは Twitter の ”Consumer Secret” の埋め込み、難読化などでよく議論されているようですが、これを完全に防ぐ方法は無いと思います。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
結局のところ、一般的にWebで行われるような、UAによるアクセス制限と似たり寄ったりのレベルにはなってしまいそうですね。
それを想定した作りにしようと思います。